# discord.py otter command using python-pixabay error

Tags: python, discord.py, pixabay

Using python-pixabay I am trying to search for otter images, then get my discord.py bot to send the image in an embed. After I search for the image and get the image, then I print it out, but it doesn't print anything, so I am pretty sure it's a problem with the image search. I get no error messages, but it just won't work.

Here is my code:

```
import pixabay
import discord

pixa = os.getenv('PIXABAY_KEY')

image = Image(pixa)

@bot.command(name='otter', help='Generates a random otter!')
async def otter(ctx):
    page = random.choice(range(0, 4))


    embed = discord.Embed(title='Otter', color=discord.Color.from_rgb)
    embed.set_image(url=ims)
    embed.set_footer(text='Powered by pixabay.')

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I didn't show all my code because there is some sensitive stuff in there, but I showed all the things you need to see. Pixabay is definitely installed, as I installed it via the instructions on the [PyPi website](https://pypi.org/project/python-pixabay)

Comment: I forgot to say, but os is installed and imported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I'm noticing is that the description is empty. Often, embeds won't send if they have empty fields, so I'd recommend checking you at least plop in a `\u200b` (empty character)* or text of some description.

Additionally, the `color` parameter doesn't seem to actually have a value. [`discord.Color.from_rgb()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Colour.from_rgb) is actually a method which takes in 3 integer values between 0-255 (#FFFFFF, #000000 not allowed).

As a side note, you can use [this](https://htmlcolorcodes.com/) website to get hex codes for the colours instead.

## Example:

```py
embed = discord.Embed(title="Otter", description="Some text!", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(85, 177, 74))

# equivalent
embed = discord.Embed(title="Otter", description="Some text!", color=0x55b14a)
```

*`description="\u200b"`

Comment: I changed this, but still does nothing.

Comment: @Oblique If you're not getting any errors, would you be able to add print statements throughout the command to see where it gets up to? Good ol' debugging haha

Comment: I changed over to using the API instead of using the python module, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Oblique Glad you got it working! Good luck with the bot :)